# Get training hyperparameters from a trained keras model

Tags: python, keras, hdf5

I am trying to figure out some of the hyperparamters used for training some old keras models I have.  They were saved as .h5 files.  When using `model.summary()`, I get the model architecture, but no additional metadata about the model.

When I open this .h5 file in notepad++, most of the file is not human readable, but there are bits that I can understand, for instance;

> {"loss_weights": null, "metrics": ["accuracy"], "sample_weight_mode":
>   null, "optimizer_config": {"config": {"decay": 0.0, "momentum":
>   0.8999999761581421, "nesterov": false, "lr": 9.999999747378752e-05}, "class_name": "SGD"}, "loss": "binary_crossentropy"}

which is not present in the output printed by `model.summary()`.

Is there a way to make these files human readable or to get a more expanded summary that includes version information and training parameters?

Comment: which hyperparameters do you want to see?

Comment: @Matias I'd like to see everything I can, excluding specific weights and biases.  I'd like to reproduce the old model, so it helps to know how it was trained.

Comment: The thing is that weights and biases are not hyper-parameters, so it will be useful to see exactly what you expect. The H5 file usually has all the information about the model, including the configuration.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to know the **hyperparams** of the layers (no of layers, no of neurons in each layer, and activation function used in each layer), you can do:

```
model.get_config()
```

To find out **loss** function used in training, do:

```
model.loss
```

Additionally, if you want to know the **Optimizer** used in the training, do:

```
model.optimizer
```

And finally, in order to find out the **learning rate** used while training, do:

```
from keras import backend as K
K.eval(m.optimizer.lr)
```

PS: Examples provided above use keras v2.3.1.

Answer (score 12):

I think what you want is the model configuration, you can get these with:

```
model.get_config()
```

It returns a "human readable" JSON string that describes the configuration of the model. You can use this to reconstruct the model and train it again, or to make changes.

Answer (score 3):

Configuration - `model.get_config()`

Optimizer config - `model.optimizer.get_config()`

Training Config  `model.history.params` (this will be empty, if model is saved and reloaded)

Loss Fuction - `model.loss`